# Listview with endless scrolling using winjs

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I need to implement endless scrolling feature in listview for windows phone 8.1 application using winjs. Is there any easiest/possible way to implement this? at first time 'n' items will be loaded, if we scroll down to reach the bottom of list next set of items will be load...and so on.

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this in a sidebar of my free ebook, [*Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition*](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), in Chapter 7. Here's that bit:

> Apart from potentially very large but known collections, other
> collections are, for all intents and purposes, essentially unbounded,
> like a news feed that might have millions of items stretching back to
> the Cenozoic Era (at least by Internet reckoning!). With such
> collections, you probably won’t know just how many items there are at
> all; the best you can do is just load another chunk when the user
> wants them.
>
> Although the ListView itself doesn’t provide support for
> automatically loading another batch of items at the appropriate time,
> it’s relatively straightforward to do within either a data source or
> an item rendering function. Just watch for item requests near the end
> of the list (however far  you want to make it), and use that as
> a trigger to load more items. Within an item renderer, check the
> position of the items being rendered, which tells you where the
> ListView’s viewport is relative to the collection. In a data source,
> watch the index or key in IListDataAdapter methods like
> itemsFromIndex, especially when the countAfter argument exceeds the
> end of the current list. Either way, you then load more items into the
> collection, changes that should generate change notifications to the
> control. The control will call the source’s getCount method in
> response and update its scrollbar accordingly.
>
> A small demonstration of this can be found in scenarios 2 and 3 of the [HTML ListView
> incremental loading behavior sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-loading-behaviors-718a4673), which adds more items to a
> Binding.List when needed from within the item renderer.

Comment: Hi Kraig : Thanks for your answer. But in that sample they used timer to load more items, so even if we don't scroll the next set of items loading automatically on that particular time delay. But i need to load the next set of items only on the item reaches the end of list. Could you please give any suggestion?

Comment: The two methods of doing that are in the answer I already wrote above. Either do it in an item rendering function (that you use in place of a declarative template so you can watch the item requests), or do it in the data source. For the latter, try this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-custom-data-4dcfb128. For rendering functions see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-item-templates-7d74826f. I talk about details in Chapter 7 of my book, but don't go into the incremental scenarios more than what I pasted above.